# Getting "The Server is not operational"

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

I'm trying to get user groups in a web application:

```
private bool GetGroups(string userName, string domain, out string result)
 {
     PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> groups;
     PrincipalContext yourDomain =  = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "fibi.corp");
     // find your user
     UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(yourDomain, userName);
            // if found - grab its groups
     if (user != null)
     {
       groups = user.GetGroups();
     }
  }
```

I'm getting

> "The Server is not operational"

exception.
I've noticed people were getting this when using the 'old' DirectoryEntry, but I'm using PrincipalContext.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the above code was searching for groups in "corp" domain which was blocked and not only in "fibi.corp".
Used the old DirectoryEntry approach with specifying "DC=fibi, DC =corp" and that solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

I found that var groups = user.GetAuthorizationGroups(); Seems to work just fine, but when I use GetGroups(); I get the same error. This seemed to fix it for me!... Please try GetAuthorizationGroups(); and see if that works!